# installation of draw2d latest version on angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, draw2d, draw2d-js

how can I install the latest version of draw2d library on angular 10?

I used the command "npm i draw2d" but the version that has been installed is 1.0.38 although the latest version is 6.1 I guess.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehGVF.png)

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have the latest version of draw2d according to npm :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/draw2d/v/1.0.37

You can also download and add it manually at https://github.com/freegroup/draw2d

To be clear, the version on npm is a package version, not the same that draw2d version of draw2d.org (http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/).

It creates confusion, I think it's a mistake from the author.

Answer (score 0):

You can test :

```
npm i draw2d@6.1
```